# Autoencoder and SVM implementation and improving AUC

Tags: python, tensorflow, svm, autoencoder, loss-function

Currently, I am using autoencoder to extract features from the fMRI images. I have a NumPy array of 9950 for each candidate and 4975 features are being extracted using autoencoder which is given SVM to predict if the candidate is suffering from a disease or not.

Here is my autoencoder model:

```
encoding_dim =4975

# this is our input placeholder
input_img = Input(shape=(9950,))
# "encoded" is the encoded representation of the input
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(input_img)
# "decoded" is the lossy reconstruction of the input
decoded = Dense(9950, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)

# this model maps an input to its reconstruction
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
print(autoencoder)
# this model maps an input to its encoded representation
encoder = Model(input_img, encoded)

# create a placeholder for an encoded (32-dimensional) input
encoded_input = Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))
# retrieve the last layer of the autoencoder model
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
# create the decoder model
decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.optimizers import Adam,SGD
opt = SGD(lr=0.001)
autoencoder.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['AUC'])
```

While I am print the AUC which remains in 40-50 range. I want to improve my encoded features so that when I give it to the SVM for classification I should receive good accuracy. Any suggestions to improve the model?